# How do I build libmySQL?

Tags: mysql, c, visual-c++, libmysql

I aim to integrate libmySQL into my executable instead of using libmySQL.dll.
I use VC++ 2008 @ Windows Vista.

I've downloaded "mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32-vs2005.zip" from
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

It contains only ".h" files with declarations. Where is the implementation code (".c" files)?

As said, I wish to be able to manipulate the code, build it as a static library (".lib") and finally integrate it into my exe.

How do I do that? Am I looking at the wrong place? Is it available at all? And if/once I do get it, does it require any special compilation? What are the steps?

Comment: I think you've mistyped the URL, unless this is a sophisticated joke. Care to fix/explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should find a .lib inside, .h .lib and .dll are enough to link it to your app
ora select 'source code' as platform instead